# Proper end of day sequence to maintain monitor config

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I've got an HP EliteBook 6930p that travels from home, where it is connected to individual cables, and work where there is a docking station.  At both locations I have an external monitor as the secondary monitor and like to have the laptop screen as the primary, i.e. with the task bar.  At the end of the day I close the laptop, which is supposed to set it to standby.  When I get home I plug in the power cord and the external monitor cord and open the computer.  When heading into work I close the computer and unplug everything.  Inevitably when I open the computer at the new location the monitors are reversed, i.e. the primary, task bar display is on the external monitor and the laptop shows the secondary, even though when i click identify the laptop has the 1.  I then have to disable the secondary display, switch the primary to the laptop and re-enable the secondary.  I've tried locking the computer before closing and occasionally that works to keep the setup in place but not always.

Any suggestions for how to keep the config in place during transport?

ed

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/)! It's [Display Profiles](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/display_profiles.asp) can quickly and painlessly get you back to a certain configuration so switching between multiple locations is a breeze.

[image]

After making your display profiles, you can easily switch between them in the system tray by right clicking the UltraMon icon and choosing from the Display Profiles menu option.

Comment: Looks like that would work, but kind of an expensive solution at $40 just to do what I would think the OS should already maintain.